# VB .net - How to limit the text file value that I can see during form load?

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, combobox

**This is somehow related to my last question yesterday**

I'm currently working on a Registration form where all the details of a student are save in a text file.

In one of my fields, I have a combobox list of all the school he/she can select.

I populated the combobox using a textfile.

The format of these values are for example: (code~school name) SCH001~Saint Thomas College

**QUESTION: How to limit the text file value that I can see during form load?**

here's sample screenshot of my data population coming from a text file:

[image]

here's a sample screenshot of my form load combobox details(coming from a textfile):

[image]

Here's the code on how I populated my Combobox:

```
 cmbLevel.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\LevelRegForm.txt"))
    cmbCurrentSchool.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\CurrentSchoolRegForm.txt"))
    cmbCurrentTrack.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\CurrentSHSTrackRegForm.txt "))
    cmbInstitution1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\SchoolRegForm.txt"))
    cmbInstitution2.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\SchoolRegForm.txt"))
    cmbInstitution3.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\SchoolRegForm.txt"))
    cmbInstitution4.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\SchoolRegForm.txt"))
    cmbInstitution5.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\SchoolRegForm.txt"))
    cmbInstitution6.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\SchoolRegForm.txt"))
    cmbCourse1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\CoursesRegForm.txt"))
    cmbCourse2.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\CoursesRegForm.txt"))
    cmbCourse3.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\CoursesRegForm.txt"))
```

**WHAT I WANT TO DO: I only want the school name to be seen in the form load(during form execution) I don't want the school code to be seen. Is there a way to hide it?**

[image]

I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to say. No hate!

Comment: how are you filling the combobox from text file to combobox. I mean post the codes for datasource of combobox.

Comment: @Nobody I added my coding for data population. Thanks

Comment: I'm asking to post codes for: Prefered Institution 1 : **combobox** <- How are you filling this combobox, post the codes for that

Comment: @Nobody sorry about that. Check out my latest edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this below code:

```
Sub FillCombobox(combo As ComboBox, filename As String)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim data As String() = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
    dt.Columns.Add("SchoolCode")
    dt.Columns.Add("SchoolName")
    For i As Integer = 0 To Data.Length - 1
        dt.Rows.Add()
        dt.Rows(i)("SchoolCode") = Data(i).Split("~"c)(0)
        dt.Rows(i)("SchoolName") = Data(i).Split("~"c)(1)
    Next
    combo.DataSource = dt
    combo.DisplayMember = "SchoolName"
    combo.ValueMember = "SchoolCode"
End Sub
```

Now change
 `cmbInstitution1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\SchoolRegForm.txt"))`

To

```
FillCombobox(cmbInstitution1, "C:\ProgramData\Doxcheck\ConfigFile\SchoolRegForm.txt")
```

This way change all the comboboxes regarding institution to the above method.

You can get the `SelectedText` (ie. school name) & `SelectedValue` (ie. school code) using this (eg: when selecting second item):

```
cmbInstitution1.Text 'Goodwill academy
cmbInstitution1.SelectedValue 'SH002
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read all lines from you school file and then add one by one 
   like this

```
    Dim schools = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("your file path")
    For Each item As String In schools
        Dim parts = item.Split("~")
        If parts IsNot Nothing And parts.Count() = 2 Then

            '' add  parts[1] to school combo box
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the answer you are proposing is in C# language.

Comment: sorry let me write in VB.Net sorry

Comment: No problem. Thank you! :--)